# Parallelization and memoization?

Tags: parallelization, memoization

I have an expensive function on discrete values,

```
f[n_] := f[n] = n^2 (* Expensive calculation *)
```

Since `f[n]` is an expensive computation, I only want to compute each value of `f` once, so I memoize the value.

Now I want to evaluate a complicated sum involving values of `f[n]`:

```
ParallelSum[f[i]f[j], {i, 1, 10}, {j, 0, i}] (* complicated sum *)
```

and it would be nice to evaluate this sum in parallel.

The problem is the code I just wrote doesn't work as expected. I am getting multiple evaluations of `f[n]` in each kernel. How can I fix my code so that a single computation of `f` is made for each value of `n` and this is communicated between kernels?

**Note:** You can assume that `f[n]` is so expensive that we can ignore the overhead involved in communicating the computed values of `f[n]` between kernels.

Comment: If you know in advance what the values of `n` are that will be involved, you could potentially just generate a list `expensiveList` of `f[n]` for the necessary `n`, export it for backup safety, and use `expensiveList[[k[n]]]` instead of `f[n]`, where `k[n]` is the index of `f[n]` in `expensiveList`. Of course, it would be preferable to use memoization, but in case that's difficult you can always use this as an alternate method.

Comment: You should look into `SetSharedFunction`. I'm not sure how much parallelization you will lose though. I tried some toy examples and it ended up slowing things down a lot.